# How can I disable the Timeline in Windows 10 April 2018 Update?

Tags: windows-10-v1803

The Windows 10 April 2018 Update includes a new feature called Timeline which tacks the activities and allows you to see what you have done earlier, sends it to Microsoft servers, so that you can resume work on a 2nd device, which is connected to the same Microsoft account when you press the `Tasks View` button in the taskbar:

[image]

How can I disable the Timeline because I don't want that my activity gets tracked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [disable this via GUI](https://mspoweruser.com/how-to-manage-timeline-in-the-windows-10-spring-creators-update/)

- Open Settings app
- Navigate to System > Multitasking.
- Look for Timeline, and toggle off `show suggestions occasionally in Timeline`.

[image]

<sup>picture source: mspoweruser.com</sup>

- navigate to Privacy > Activity History
- disable the 2 checkboxes and set the toggle entry to `off`

[image]

<sup>picture source: mspoweruser.com</sup>

or [registry](https://www.deskmodder.de/wiki/index.php?title=Zeitleiste_Timeline_deaktivieren_aktivieren_Windows_10#Zeitleiste.2C_Timeline_deaktivieren_in_der_Registry_deaktivieren).

- run `regedit.exe` go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`
- create a new DWORD (32Bit) with the name `EnableActivityFeed` and set it to `0`.
- create a new DWORD (32Bit) with the name `PublishUserActivities` and set it to `0`.
- create a new DWORD (32Bit) with the name `UploadUserActivities` and set it to `0`.

[image]

<sup>picture source: deskmodder.de</sup>

Now you have the old Taskview back.