# How to restore Win10 TaskView UI to how it was before the April update?

Tags: windows-10

The latest win10 update introduced a timeline in the task view. It's possible to disable this, which I did, but I am still annoyed by the new UI.

How can I
a)
completely revert to the old UI without having to undo the update and permanently stop installing updates?

or

b)
at least move the desktops previews back to the bottom of the taskView Screen instead of the top, where it is now?

There's no reason for this question, apart from the fact that I like the old UI way better and am annoyed that Windows did not ask for permission before changing such a thing.

To be clear, an image where the desktop previews are where I want them ([Source](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/operating-systems/1403610/how-to-switch-tasks-faster-in-windows-10)):
[image]

Note that this is not a duplicate of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1318559/how-can-i-disable-the-timeline-in-windows-10-april-2018-update/1318560#1318560), because I am not asking about how to disable the timeline. As mentioned, I have already done that.
My taskView screen now looks like this:
[image: taskview without timeline]
Note that **the miniature desktops are at the top** and **I have to scroll to see all open windows**, which I did not need to do before the update.

Comment: stop using win 10 :) win 10 is not OS - MS switched doing it as a service - so there is no new OS planned this will just be constantly and unpredictably changing and MS will use their users as testers - so if you want to be unpaid tester for MS - stop using any OS above win 7; otherwise - just live with that - MS will change anything as they want and it's waste of time to try to revert everything as its not feasible always

Comment: @Biswapriyo wrong, by turning Timeline off [as shown in my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1318560/174557)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you, but this is not what I have asked for. It's a very useful answer for people who don't find these settings, but it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: what is your issue? That desktops entries are now on top? this was changed for timeline. Install 1607 LTSB (if you have enterprise license) to have old view. you have to accept that Microsoft changes UI very often in Windows 10. if you don't do, use Windows 8.1 or go to Apple.

Comment: I am fine with them changing it @magicandre1981, but I want to be able to change it back. I have in the meantime taken more an issue with the fact that I don't see all open windows anymore without scrolling.
I have now reverted the update and will not update further (and maybe go back to win7), but I would still be interested in how this can be solved.

Comment: you can't revert this. Microsoft needs to change the view but I doubt that will happen.

Comment: Then, if you're sure, I suppose "You can't" would be a valid answer. Feel free to write that and I'll accept it (since I already decided to revert the whole update anyways)